# Migrate customer and transaction data from CSV to MongoDB

Tags: java, beginner, spring, mongodb, junit

I wrote a Java Spring Boot application with MongoDB that on every application start loads customer, account type and transaction details from CSV files to MongoDB. It has one end point that returns transactions for a given `customerId` and `accountType` (for example customer id 1,3,5 etc. or account type "ALL"). The main target is to return demanded data (and sorted ascending by transaction amount) as fast as possible (read time matters most). I also wrote 3 tests to test this end point.

My service:

```
package com.colliers.mongodb.service;

import com.colliers.mongodb.exception.TransactionNotFoundException;
import com.colliers.mongodb.model.DTO.TransactionDTO;
import com.colliers.mongodb.model.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class TransactionService {

    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public TransactionService(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
       this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    public List<TransactionDTO> getTransactions(String accountType, String customerId) throws TransactionNotFoundException {
        final List<String> accounts = Arrays.asList(accountType.split(","));
        final List<String> customers = Arrays.asList(customerId.split(","));

        Query query = new Query();
        query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "transactionAmount"));

        if(accountType.equals("") || accountType.equals("ALL"));
        else {
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("accountType.accountType").in(accounts));
        }

        if(customerId.equals("") || customerId.equals("ALL"));
        else {
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("customer.id").in(customers));
        }

        List<Transaction> transactions = this.mongoTemplate.find(query, Transaction.class, "transactions");

        if(transactions.isEmpty()) {
            throw new TransactionNotFoundException("No Transactions found.");
        }

        List<TransactionDTO> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for(var t : transactions) {
            TransactionDTO transactionDTO = TransactionDTO.builder()
                    .transactionDate(t.getTransactionDate())
                    .transactionId(t.getId())
                    .transactionAmount(t.getTransactionAmount())
                    .accountTypeName(t.getAccountType().getName())
                    .firstName(t.getCustomer().getFirstName())
                    .lastName(t.getCustomer().getLastName())
                    .build();

            result.add(transactionDTO);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
package com.colliers.mongodb.controller;

import com.colliers.mongodb.model.DTO.TransactionDTO;
import com.colliers.mongodb.service.TransactionService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
class Controller {

    private TransactionService service;

    @Autowired
    Controller(TransactionService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping("/transactions")
    ResponseEntity<List<TransactionDTO>> getTransactionsByAccountTypeAndCustomerId(
        @RequestParam(value = "account_type") String accountType, @RequestParam(value = "customer_id") String customerId) {

        String regex = "^(^$)|(ALL)|(([1-9][0-9]*)((,[1-9][0-9]*)*))$";

        if(!accountType.matches(regex) || !customerId.matches(regex)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(this.service.getTransactions(accountType, customerId), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

My AppInit - database seeder:

```
package com.colliers.mongodb.configuration;

import com.colliers.mongodb.model.AccountType;
import com.colliers.mongodb.model.Customer;
import com.colliers.mongodb.model.Transaction;
import com.colliers.mongodb.repository.AccountTypeRepository;
import com.colliers.mongodb.repository.CustomerRepository;
import com.colliers.mongodb.repository.TransactionRepository;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBeanBuilder;
import com.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
class AppInit implements CommandLineRunner {

    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    private TransactionRepository transactionRepository;
    private AccountTypeRepository accountTypeRepository;
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public AppInit(CustomerRepository customerRepository, TransactionRepository transactionRepository,
                   AccountTypeRepository accountTypeRepository, MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {

        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
        this.transactionRepository = transactionRepository;
        this.accountTypeRepository = accountTypeRepository;
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        mongoTemplate.dropCollection("customers");
        mongoTemplate.dropCollection("transactions");
        mongoTemplate.dropCollection("accountypes");
        mongoTemplate.createCollection("customers");
        mongoTemplate.createCollection("transactions");
        mongoTemplate.createCollection("accountypes");

        File customersCSV = new File("src/main/resources/static/customers.csv");
        File transactionsCSV = new File("src/main/resources/static/transactions.csv");
        File accountypesCSV = new File("src/main/resources/static/accountypes.csv");

        Map<String, Customer> customers = parseCustomers(customersCSV);
        customerRepository.saveAll(customers.values());

        Map<String, AccountType> accountTypes = parseAccountTypes(accountypesCSV);
        accountTypeRepository.saveAll(accountTypes.values());

        List<Transaction> transactions = parseTransactions(transactionsCSV);
        for(var t : transactions) {
            t.setAccountType(accountTypes.get(t.getAccountTypeNumber()));
            t.setCustomer(customers.get(t.getCustomerId()));
        }

        transactionRepository.saveAll(transactions);
    }

    private List<Transaction> parseTransactions(File file) throws Exception {
        HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<Transaction> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<>();
        strategy.setType(Transaction.class);

        Map<String, String> columnMapping = new HashMap<>();
        columnMapping.put("transaction_id", "id");
        columnMapping.put("transaction_amount", "transactionAmount");
        columnMapping.put("account_type", "accountTypeNumber");
        columnMapping.put("customer_id", "customerId");
        columnMapping.put("transaction_date", "transactionDate");

        strategy.setColumnMapping(columnMapping);

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file.getPath()));
        CsvToBean<Transaction> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Transaction>(reader)
                .withMappingStrategy(strategy)
                .build();

        return csvToBean.parse();
    }

    private Map<String, Customer> parseCustomers(File file) throws IOException {
        HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<Customer> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<>();
        strategy.setType(Customer.class);

        Map<String, String> columnMapping = new HashMap<>();
        columnMapping.put("id", "id");
        columnMapping.put("first_name", "firstName");
        columnMapping.put("last_name", "lastName");
        columnMapping.put("last_login_balance", "lastLoginBalance");

        strategy.setColumnMapping(columnMapping);

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file.getPath()));
        CsvToBean<Customer> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Customer>(reader)
                .withMappingStrategy(strategy)
                .build();

        return csvToBean.parse().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Customer::getId, c -> c));
    }

    private Map<String, AccountType> parseAccountTypes(File file) throws IOException {
        HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<AccountType> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<>();
        strategy.setType(AccountType.class);


        Map<String, String> columnMapping = new HashMap<>();
        columnMapping.put("account_type", "accountType");
        columnMapping.put("name", "name");

        strategy.setColumnMapping(columnMapping);

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file.getPath()));
        CsvToBean<AccountType> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<AccountType>(reader)
                .withMappingStrategy(strategy)
                .build();

        return csvToBean.parse().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(AccountType::getAccountType, a -> a));
    }
}
```

My ControllerTest:

```
package com.colliers.mongodb.controller;

import com.colliers.mongodb.model.AccountType;
import com.colliers.mongodb.model.Customer;
import com.colliers.mongodb.model.DTO.TransactionDTO;
import com.colliers.mongodb.model.Transaction;
import com.colliers.mongodb.service.TransactionService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    private Controller controller;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        TransactionService service = new TransactionService(mongoTemplate);
        controller = new Controller(service);
    }

    @Test
    void test() {}

    @Test
    void getTransactionsByAccountTypeAndCustomerIdWithWIthOneAccountTypeAndOneCustomerIdTest() {
        Transaction t1 = Transaction.builder()
                .id(700)
                .transactionAmount(600.11)
                .accountType(new AccountType("1", "1", "checking account"))
                .customer(new Customer("1", "Elliot", "Alderson", 199))
                .transactionDate("2017-03-06 13:23:11")
                .build();

        when(this.mongoTemplate.find(ArgumentMatchers.any(Query.class), ArgumentMatchers.eq(Transaction.class),
                                            ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(t1));

        ResponseEntity<List<TransactionDTO>> result = controller.getTransactionsByAccountTypeAndCustomerId("1", "1");
        assertThat(result.getBody().get(0).getAccountTypeName()).isEqualTo("checking account");
        assertThat(result.getBody().get(0).getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Elliot");
    }

    @Test
    void getTransactionsByAccountTypeAndCustomerIdWithOneCustomerIdAndEmptyAccountTypeTest() {
        Transaction t1 = Transaction.builder()
                .id(700)
                .transactionAmount(600.11)
                .accountType(new AccountType("1", "1", "checking account"))
                .customer(new Customer("1", "Elliot", "Alderson", 199))
                .transactionDate("2017-03-06 13:23:11")
                .build();

        Transaction t2 = Transaction.builder()
                .id(723)
                .transactionAmount(524.32)
                .accountType(new AccountType("2", "2", "saving account"))
                .customer(new Customer("1", "Elliot", "Alderson", 199))
                .transactionDate("2013-08-04 23:57:38")
                .build();

        when(mongoTemplate.find(ArgumentMatchers.any(Query.class), ArgumentMatchers.eq(Transaction.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(t1, t2));

        ResponseEntity<List<TransactionDTO>> result = controller.getTransactionsByAccountTypeAndCustomerId("", "1");
        assertThat(result.getBody().get(0).getAccountTypeName()).isEqualTo("checking account");
        assertThat(result.getBody().get(0).getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Elliot");

        assertThat(result.getBody().get(1).getAccountTypeName()).isEqualTo("saving account");
        assertThat(result.getBody().get(1).getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Elliot");
    }

    @Test
    void getTransactionsByAccountTypeAndCustomerIdWithEmptyAccountTypeAndALLCustomerIdTest() {
        Transaction t1 = Transaction.builder()
                .id(700)
                .transactionAmount(600.11)
                .accountType(new AccountType("1", "1", "checking account"))
                .customer(new Customer("1", "Elliot", "Alderson", 199))
                .transactionDate("2017-03-06 13:23:11")
                .build();

        Transaction t2 = Transaction.builder()
                .id(723)
                .transactionAmount(524.32)
                .accountType(new AccountType("2", "2", "saving account"))
                .customer(new Customer("1", "Elliot", "Alderson", 199))
                .transactionDate("2013-08-04 23:57:38")
                .build();

        Transaction t3 = Transaction.builder()
                .id(200)
                .transactionAmount(500)
                .accountType(new AccountType("1", "1", "checking account"))
                .customer(new Customer("2", "Tyrell", "Wellick", 10000))
                .transactionDate("2020-10-07 23:59:59")
                .build();

        Transaction t4 = Transaction.builder()
                .id(540)
                .transactionAmount(1000)
                .accountType(new AccountType("2", "2", "saving account"))
                .customer(new Customer("2", "Tyrell", "Wellick", 10000))
                .transactionDate("2018-02-01 12:05:18")
                .build();

        when(mongoTemplate.find(ArgumentMatchers.any(Query.class), ArgumentMatchers.eq(Transaction.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(t1, t2, t3, t4));

        ResponseEntity<List<TransactionDTO>> result = controller.getTransactionsByAccountTypeAndCustomerId("", "ALL");
        assertThat(result.getBody().get(0).getAccountTypeName()).isEqualTo("checking account");
        assertThat(result.getBody().get(0).getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Elliot");

        assertThat(result.getBody().get(1).getAccountTypeName()).isEqualTo("saving account");
        assertThat(result.getBody().get(1).getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Elliot");

        assertThat(result.getBody().get(2).getAccountTypeName()).isEqualTo("checking account");
        assertThat(result.getBody().get(2).getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Tyrell");

        assertThat(result.getBody().get(3).getAccountTypeName()).isEqualTo("saving account");
        assertThat(result.getBody().get(3).getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Tyrell");
    }
}
```

This application is all that I am currently capable of (I want also to note, that I'm not a professional software dev - still learning and want to become one in the future). In order to keep improving I need feedback concerning topics like "clean code", don't do that - do that, use different library etc. I'm not interested in discussing app security (topic on different time). Below link to GitHub repo.

https://github.com/dstarostka/mongodb

Comment: For anyone in the Close Queue the question has been updated and no longer violates the context rule.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Thanks a lot for that, it saves a lot of time!